# Animate Text Display In-A-Way That Simulates Magical Ink Writing in a Magical Book

Tags: ipad, graphics, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a Cocos2d iPad game that includes a magical book. From time-to-time, new text appears in the book.

I would like to animate the new text in a way that looks like ink magically appearing on the page of the book. I have tried the following (but am not happy with the quality):

- Outside the game: create the text as an image, create a second image of the text and blur it. During runtime: fade from the blurred text image to the non-blurred text image
- Runtime: create random ink dots in the region of the text, scale the ink dots until the obscure much of the area, and then fade them to out leaving the text behind.

My question is this: What is a creative way to have text look like it is magically appearing on an old page of a magic book using Cocos2d on the iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a particle system (choose one from the examples coming with cocos and customize) which will move on your book and new text characters will appear under it ?

Or it can be a big system to cover all the text line. So it will appear (particles) then text will be created under it and particles emitter will stop, so the current particles will disappear beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cocos, but how about just slowly increasing the text color saturation starting from white (assuming your page color is white).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it look like it's being magically written, you could create the text as an image, and have a second image similar to the book background on top, and slide it to the right thus slowly revealing the unmasked text.

If you wanna get fancy, remember that fonts are defined as Bezier curves. These can be animated. In this manner you could create some awesome effects, although the coding would probably not be effortless.